# Have Flex variable display in getURL() method

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

I am trying to have a variable called myString available for a button click event. Inside that  button I have something like this. click="getURL(myString);"

Right not it is displaying as an empty string. I know it is there because I can see it in my handleResultMethod. How do I need to code this to make the myString variable available for the getURL() method?

Here is my complete code on pastebin.
http://pastebin.com/6NvinqYt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *myString* variable being referenced in the button's click handler is the "global" *myString* variable for your entire TitleWindow subclass.  However, when you set *myString* inside your *handleResult* function you're using the var declaration, which is creating a separate *myString* variable that is unique to the *handleResult* function.

Simply make the following change and you should be okay (~line 40):

```
var myString:String = evt.result.toString();
```

to

```
myString = evt.result.toString();
```

Comment: This worked great! Thank you for taking the time to answer this Kalen. You Flex skills are outstanding.